# Separate Work and Personal Profiles on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have been using multiple profiles on Chrome for both Work and Personal. In preparing to exit Work, I noticed that the majority of my personal Saved Passwords are available in my Work profile (and vice versa). I opened both profiles in new windows, and tried deleting from the Work profile's list of passwords, and noticed the change reflected (after refresh) in the Personal profile. I created a VM and install Ubuntu, and logged in with the Work profile, and noticed that changes aren't reflect in/from there... ie, I delete in Host machine or Guest machine, and those removals are not reflected in each other... but Host-Work delete shows in Host-Personal.

Anyone know if there is a way to remove all my Personal data from the Work account, without losing it in my Personal profile as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a "better" way, but what I noticed is that if I deleted stuff in Chrome on the host machine, it affected both accounts... so deleting personal accounts on the Work profile, still removed from my Personal profile too. However, if I delete in the VM (with Work profile only), then only the Work profile is affected on the Host machine. I was able to then cherry pick in the VM, and verify in the Host Personal profile that I retained my accounts, but removed in the Host Work profile. I even did "stop and clear" in the Host Work profile, and then synced again and no personal accounts came back.

Hope this helps someone else.